# Python: Why is one element in this list not being printed?

Tags: python, list, graph

I am trying to print the distinct nodes in a graph when given a list of edges with the following:

```
def find_nodes(graph):
    # get the distinct nodes from the edges
    nodes = []
    l = len(graph)
    for i in range(l):
        edge = graph[i]
        n1 = edge[0]
        n2 = edge[1]
        if n1 not in nodes:
            nodes.append(n1)
        if n2 not in nodes:
            nodes.append(n2)
    return nodes

graph = ((1,2),(2,3), (3,1))
print find_nodes(graph)
```

But I only get `(1,2)` how am i missing the `3`?

Comment: It prints `[1, 2, 3]` for me.

Comment: With Python 2.7.3, I tried the code and it worked fine `print find_nodes(graph)` => `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Same here: http://ideone.com/NhyFb

Comment: Using the windows command prompt...is this possibly relevant?

Comment: `nodes` should be a set, not a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at the text you've inserted, it looks like you're mixing tabs and spaces as left-hand whitespace:

This can be confirmed by looking at the repr of each line:

```
'    def find_nodes(graph):'
'        # get the distinct nodes from the edges'
'        nodes = []'
'        l = len(graph)'
'        for i in range(l):'
'        \tedge = graph[i]'
'        \tn1 = edge[0]'
'        \tn2 = edge[1]'
'        \tif n1 not in nodes:'
'        \t\tnodes.append(n1)'
'        \tif n2 not in nodes:'
'        \t\tnodes.append(n2)'
'    \treturn nodes'
```

This can result in lines not being indented to the level you think they are.  Here's what I get as a result from copying and pasting your input into a console:

```
>>> s = """
...     def find_nodes(graph):
...         # get the distinct nodes from the edges
...         nodes = []
...         l = len(graph)
...         for i in range(l):
...             edge = graph[i]
...             n1 = edge[0]
...             n2 = edge[1]
...             if n1 not in nodes:
...                     nodes.append(n1)
...             if n2 not in nodes:
...                     nodes.append(n2)
...             return nodes
...     
...     graph = ((1,2),(2,3), (3,1))
...     print find_nodes(graph)
... 
... """
```

It looks to me like the `return nodes` line will be executed too early.  Write the code into a file and use the `python -tt` option to check for whitespace problems.

Comment: Was just about to add this as an answer...indeed return wasn't indented properly...oh python..i shall soon get used to thee :)

Comment: You should really make sure you're using a Python-friendly editor which uses four-space tabs for indentation.  Anything else is just going to lead to headaches..

Answer (score 0):

Works for me too.

A possibly more pythonic form, using set:

```
def find_nodes(graph):
    return list({element
                 for edge in graph
                 for element in edge})
```

Comment: still doesn't print the last nodes!..it looks like my loop is stopping after the first edge..not sure why

Comment: If your using the windows prompt, perhaps you are typing enter before you should? Sounds confusing...